# Python 3 regular expression returning unexpected result

Tags: python, regex

I don't understand why the two follow code blocks give a different result for the test case. The first code block returns 2016 as expected, but when a make a small change the second one returns None.

Here's the first one, which returns '2016' as expected

```
import re
date = '24 Jan 2016'
def func(line):
    month_regex = re.search('(\d{1,2})\s(Jan)\s(\d{2,4})', line)
    if month_regex:
        year = month_regex.group(3)
    return year
func(date)
```

Then, I add "(uary)?" to the regex and for some reason, it returns None. Note that the results of group(1) and group(2) work the same in both cases.

```
import re
date = '24 Jan 2016'
def func(line):
    month_regex = re.search('(\d{1,2})\s(Jan(uary)?)\s(\d{2,4})', line)
    if month_regex:
        year = month_regex.group(3)
    return year
func(date)
```

Why does the second code block return None?

Comment: The first snippet returns the year. See https://ideone.com/1v7FQe. The second snippet [returns `None`](https://ideone.com/BWIkcq), because the 3rd group did not match. What is your final goal? Return the year? Then [use `.group(4)` in the second snippet](https://ideone.com/6qT6Jr).

Comment: Why doesn't the third group match? Wouldn't \d{2,4} match 2016?

Comment: But `(uary)?` *is* a **capturing** group, and it is assigned ID=3 (since it is the third capturing  group in the pattern). `(\d{2,4})` is the 4th group.

Comment: Ah, I meant to make it a non-capturing group. Thanks! Go ahead and add that as an answer and I'll select it.

Comment: Refining your patterns with an online regular expression tester really helps.  There are several that use Python flavored regexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the second regex contains an extra `(uary)?` *capturing* group, the match result now contains 4 groups and `.group(3)` no longer maps to the year, but to the optional `uary` substring. And since the input has no `uary` after `Jan`, the group value is *None*, it was just left uninitialized.

The best way to add optional groups while keeping the group structure intact is via [*non-capturing* groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon):

```
month_regex = re.search(r'(\d{1,2})\s(Jan(?:uary)?)\s(\d{2,4})', line)
                                         ^^
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/6qT6Jr).

Here, the groups are the following:

```
(\d{1,2})\s(Jan(?:uary)?)\s(\d{2,4})
|-- 1 --|  |---- 2 -----|  |-- 3 --|
```

Besides, it is best practice to use raw string literals for regex pattern declaration, just to avoid further misunderstanding when you add word boundaries or backreferences.